# Only last image in array uploads with Alamofire Swift 3

Tags: swift, image, asynchronous, file-upload, alamofire

I need to upload several images to an API at a time. I am using Alamofire to upload images and the API only allows one image to be uploaded per request.

I have an array of images to be uploaded and I am going through the array and making a request each time. Each image appears to upload correctly but then when I check the database only the last image has been uploaded. Each call prints a response with status code 200 and prints "SUCCESSFUL" when it is complete, but only the last in the array actually uploads.

```
for (index, image) in self.imageArray.enumerated() {
        self.uploadImages(photoIndex: index, photo: image.image, fileName: image.imageName, completion: { (true) in
            print("SUCCESSFUL")
        })
}
```

I have also tried using a DispatchQueue, but that didn't work either:

```
 let serialQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "serialQueue")
```

And inside the for loop

```
serialQueue.async {
 //self.uploadImages...
}
```

I've tried a few more things, with no success. How would I be able to fix this?

Also, here is my uploadImages function

```
func uploadImages(photoIndex: Int, photo: UIImage, fileName: String, completion: @escaping (_ Success : Bool?) -> ())
    {
        var success: Bool? = nil

        let url : String? = //url
        // define parameters
        let parameters = [
            "photoIndex": "\(photoIndex)"]

        Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(photo, 1)
            {
                multipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: "photo", fileName: fileName, mimeType: "image/png")
            }

            for (key, value) in parameters {
                multipartFormData.append((value.data(using: .utf8))!, withName: key)
            }}, to: url!, method: .post,
                encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
                    switch encodingResult {
                    case .success(let upload, _, _):
                        upload.response { [weak self] response in
                            guard let strongSelf = self else {
                                return
                            }
                            success = true
                            debugPrint(response)
                            completion(success)

                        }
                    case .failure(let encodingError):
                        print("error:\(encodingError)")
                        }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use multipart form data to upload the any media file below is the code snippet to upload multiple video

```
for (key , value) in arrMediaUpload {
                        if let image = value as? UIImage {
                            if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,0.9) {
                                print("key => \(key)")
                                multipartFormData.append(imageData as Data, withName: key, fileName: "\(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970).jpg", mimeType: "image/*")
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't think this is my problem though. I added the code for my function that uploads the image. It works, but when I use it in a loop, only the last image in the loop actually gets uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

I am not that good in Swift so take this answer with a grain of salt but I do not see were you are adding any new keys to your dictionary.  So since there is only one key there would be only one value.  Therefore the for loop would only be done one time.